# Best way font file load depend on text script (Latin, Arabic, Cyrillic)

Tags: javascript

I use google fonts.

When I put all font scripts (Latin, Arabic, Cyrillic, etc) together - font file size about 500Kb.

I want split each script in separate font file and load font with CSS depending on text in Javascript variable.

Javascript text examples

```
var text_to_display = 'This is English text';
```

or

```
var text_to_display = 'Это текст на Русском';
```

or

```
var text_to_display = 'هذا هو نص اللغة الإنجليزية';
```

Is there any way to recognize text script in javascript?

Comment: Perhaps this? http://richt.me/2012/09/guesslanguage-js/  _A JavaScript language detection library based on trigram statistical analysis. This library works equally well when run in either the Browser or Node.js._

Comment: This lib works well :)

Comment: Well, quite, I've been unable to recognize English (which is surprising) but I've been able to recognize Russian and Arabic. Not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but it seems you can easily detect most of the languages through that.

Comment: Vietnamese detected - I wonder